# Fluent assertion, ThenBeInAscendingOrder propertyExpression

Tags: c#, mstest, fluent-assertions

I can't make it work, any help will be much apreciated.
There is a list of entities from query response where I would like to test if they are in particular order, and I wish to make the comparison with Fluent assertion library but I have been struggling for hours with the solution.
So far I got this:

```
var prop = typeof(BgTaskListItemDto).GetProperty(orderableAttribute);

listResponse.Data.Entities
     .Select(e => prop.GetValue(e))
     .Should().BeInDescendingOrder()
     .And
     .ThenBeInAscendingOrder(
           e => Expression.Property(               
               Expression.Constant(object:e,
                                   type:typeof(BgTaskListItemDto)),
                                   propertyName:nameof(BgTaskListItemDto.Id)));
```

where  `orderableAttribute`

is from `[DataTestMethod],[DataRow(nameof(BgTaskListItemDto.AccountId))]`

evaluating the expression property self return valid data, like:

```
Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(e, typeof(BgTaskListItemDto)), nameof(BgTaskListItemDto.Id))
```

or even:

```
var x = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(e, typeof(BgTaskListItemDto)), nameof(BgTaskListItemDto.Id))).Compile();
```

returns value where the e.g.: `Id` can be found, but using it as parameter for `ThenBeInAscendingOrder` throw exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 
Expression <Property(Constant(e, BgTaskDTOs.BgTaskListItemDto), "Id")> cannot be used to select a member. (Parameter 'expression')
```

What am I missing? What is the proper use for that method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to generate a dynamic select expression you should be using a `ParameterExpressiond` and a `PropertyExpression`. But your sample doesn't even need it.  `ThenBeInAscendingOrder(q=> q.Id)` would do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just write the expression as you would any other lambda. Try performing the projection as part of `.BeInDescendingOrder()` instead of calling `.Select()` first — FluentAssertions typically gives the most informative assertion messages if you avoid using `.Select()` entirely.

```cs
var prop = typeof(BgTaskListItemDto).GetProperty(orderableAttribute);

listResponse.Data.Entities
     .Should().BeInDescendingOrder(e => prop.GetValue(e))
     .And.ThenBeInAscendingOrder(e => e.Id);
```

`Expression.Lambda` and its related methods are most useful for metaprogramming. If you're reaching for those methods just to do something statically-typed, you have very likely missed a much easier solution.

Comment: Actually you have right, the Select() was one problem, but still it throws an exception:
`threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Expression <Convert(value(BgTaskControllerTests+<>c__DisplayClass21_0).prop.GetValue(e), DateTime)> cannot be used to select a member. (Parameter 'expression')`

Comment: `.BeInDescendingOrder(e => prop.GetValue(e))` this part seems to be problematic. I think that is why op is seeking some dynamic solution.

Comment: Yes @Eldar, that is the problematic, and as @Tullo_x86 pointed out, and according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245755/12743268 article, where `BeEquivalentTo()` has an option param whit this situation should be solved, I will have to chose or an extension method, or the test should not be parameterized.
Thank you for your answers, I will mark this question solved. If anyone has an easy solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment mentioned, according to this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57245755/12743268):
`ThenBeInAscendingOrder` accept only property expression.
So far I don't see any way to override this, only writing an own extension could hide the workaround.
Something like this:

```
 public static List<T> OrderByAttributeDesc<T>(string orderableAttribute, List<T> response, string pkProperty)
        {
            if (!response.IsAny())
            {
                return response;
            }
            var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(orderableAttribute, response);
            var pkPropertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(pkProperty, response);

            var entities = response.OrderByDescending(e => propertyInfo.GetValue(e, null)).ThenBy(e => pkPropertyInfo.GetValue(e, null)).ToList();
            return entities;
        }
```

and then assert the collections in content with fluent collection assertion with configuration options if needed.